# How to remove freezes which are called by image decoding

Tags: three.js, freeze

When i start moving in game, i see some freezes, that happened only once, after recording with dev tools, i saw that freezes are called by Image Decode(as i understand it's decoding textures for my geometries). So is there any way to "precode" images, and start game without that freezes?

[recorder screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPdk7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to mitigate this problem is the usage of [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap). With this API, the image decode is going to happen in a separate thread without blocking the animation loop. In `three.js` you can use [ImageBitmapLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/ImageBitmapLoader) as a more performant substitute to `ImageLoader`. Have a look at the following example to see the loader in action:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_imagebitmap.html

Comment: Does it mean that if separate thread is still decoding images, camera could spawn in empty scene(while decoding not finished)?

Comment: Basically yes. But this is still better than heavy frame drops^^.

Comment: Have a look at the following talk for more information. `ImageBitmap` is discussed right at the beginning of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkDd-x0EkFU

Comment: An other solution is to use compressed textures. But this approach is more advanced since you have to convert all your textures to specific formats. Besides, there is no texture compression format that is supported by all types of devices.

Comment: Unfortunately browser support for ImageBitmap is quite poor (as of 2018)... Technically Chrome and Firefox support it, but Firefox's implementation has serious limitations. The alternative is [texture compression](https://github.com/timvanscherpenzeel/texture-compressor), which takes a lot of work to support all devices. But at least then it's possible to support all devices. :/ You could also try [incremental texture upload](https://github.com/spite/THREE.UpdatableTexture) but I haven't heard whether this works well or not.